# SimpleInjector – Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, simple-injector

I use nuget simple injector mvc integration quick start to install simple injector v2.5.2 and related packages to my helloworld mvc project. It works fine in my local express IIS. But after I upload it to production IIS server, it throws exception

```
  [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]

  ....

  Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor
```

The SimpleInjectorInitializer class code snippet as below.

```
            var container = new Container();
            container.Register<IService, Service>();
            container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            container.Verify();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973238/simpleinjector-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object) can't help me, DependencyResolver.SetResolver is already called.

How to fix it? Did my production IIS miss any configuration?

Comment: Did you add a virtual directory for your site? I expect that you placed your code in a subfolder without marking this as virtual directory.

Comment: Can you post the code of your Service class please ?